# Android - Load and Unload Libraries in Run Time

Tags: android, android-library, android-sdk-tools

Sample Usecase : I added a functionality to my app, which uses a scan sdk. But as soon as i added this, it increased my app size by 25MB. This part of the functionality is used only once by the user when he logs in. So is there any way i can load this functionality in runtime and unload it after the work is completed? I do not want this code to bloat the app all time.

I see Games doing this, they load helper libraries using zip when you launch the game and delete it when done. But i am not sure how it is done. Can anyone throw some light on this and how i can also achieve the same for my functionality?

Let me know if my question is unclear. Not sure if i have conveyed rightly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download some necessary parts of your app on demand.

Restrictions:

1. Such behavior is enable only for API 21+
2. You should use app bundle

This mechanism's called Dynamic Delivery and has four use cases: At-install delivery, On demand delivery, Conditional delivery, Instant delivery.

[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery) provides a lot of information and code samples too.